# How can I extract an RAR whose file names are non-Unicode in Linux?

Tags: linux, encoding, rar

I have an RAR archive whose file names are in GB2312 rather than Unicode. So after I extracted it, there were many "invalid encoding" warnings.

It's said that the official utilities can handle the issue but I'm using a Raspberry Pi whose processor is ARM. Only x86 and x64 versions are provided on their [official website](http://www.rarlabs.com/download.htm).

So how can I extract the archive normally on an ARM based machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Unix utilities for these jobs are `iconv` and `recode`.

Basically, after `unrar`ing the archive in an empty directory, you check the **exact** character set with the command `file`:

```sh
$ file -bi MyFileName
  text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

and now you can change the character set by means of either one of

```
 iconv -f gb2312 -t utf8 filename > newfilename
 recode UTF-8 filename
```

Notice: `recode` operates on the files `in place`, so you  may want to try it out on some copies, before unleashing it on the real data.

If you also need  to translate the file names:

```sh
for i in *; do 
     newi=$(echo "$i" | iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8)
     mv "$i" "newi"
done
```

I do not know whether you may use `iconv` as a filter on `unrar` itself, something like

```
unrar YourArchive -p | iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8 > somefile
```